# Display 0 if no results from view

Tags: 7, views, users, nodes

I have created a view to show users their uploaded content. It works well enough. Now if the user has not created any content then the view should output 0 or some custom message.

In earlier versions, there used to be a Empty Text field under Basic settings. I am using Drupal 7 with the latest Views.

So after some searc, I found it should occur under "No Results Behavior" in "Advanced Settings" but I do not seem to find an empty text there. I found "Global text" so there I write my message, but it does not display anything if the view is empty.

Do you have any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: use global text area, after saving, clear cache.

Comment: i tried but still it shows nothing

Comment: Does your message include any HTML? There's always the possibility it's getting removed by a filter.

Comment: Also, does the message show up in preview mode?

Comment: no there's no HTML and it does not show up in the preview area

Comment: Do you have active the devel module? Sometimes with my views I have problems if I have activate it. Try to disable it if you have.

Answer (score 4):

Click on **NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR** on the right side.

[image]

Add a **Global: Text area**

[image]

Enjoy...

Comment: thanks but as i said i have already tried that...it still shows nothing

Comment: @Shradha then there is some result for sure.

Comment: but it is empty

Answer (score 0):

I was also not able to get it show up after setting up 'NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR' in my view. I realized the problem was with the template file. So, I copied the code from the views-view.tpl.php file and got it working again. Of course, I had to adjust the code. Here it is, in case you want to see it:

> ```
>   if(isset($empty)){
>             print $empty;
>     }
> ```